# Including other functions in quicksort

Tags: haskell, quicksort

following problem occured: I'm trying to implement a `quickSort` function which sorts a list of tuples of the form `[(Name,(Day,Month,Year)]`. I wrote the functions `tupleTurn` and `dateTurn` which produce following Tuples `((Year,Month,Day),Name)`.

```
type firstname = String
type lastname = String
type day = String
type month = String
type year =  String
type name = (lastname,firstname)
type date = (day,month,year)
type person = (name, date)

tupleTurn :: (name,date)->(date,name)
tupleTurn (a,b) = (b,a) 

dateTurn :: ((day,month,year),name) ->(year,month,day),name)
dateTurn ((a,b,c),x) = ((c,b,a),x)
```

They both work perfectly fine one by one to get the desired list of tuples. Finally I want to sort this changed list by quicksort. So I implemented:

```
quickSortDate :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quickSortDate [] =[]
quickSortDate (x:xs) = quickSort ([y |y<- xs,y<=x]) ++ [x] ++ quickSort([y |y<- xs,y>x])
    where x = dateTurn (tupleTurn x); xs = dateTurn (tupleTurn xs)
```

The error message:

```
datelist.hs:42:22:Couldn't match 
    expected type ‘[(Name, Datum)]’ 
    with actual type ‘(t0, t1)’
In the pattern: (xs, ys)
In the pattern: (x, y) : (xs, ys)
In an equation for ‘tupleTurnList’: 
    tupleTurnList ((x, y) : (xs, ys))= [tupleTurn (x, y) :: tupleTurn (xs, ys)]
```

I guess the problem is the part where it tries to put `xs` into the functions, or?

Comment: The code you’ve pasted contains many errors that let me think it’s definitely not the code you actually work on. The first types are not valid, a parenthesis is missing on dateTurn signature and you call the quickSort function instead of quickSortDate. Could you please post the actual code ?

Comment: Guessing from that, the error message you get is absolutely normal. You defined quickSortDate as a function taking a list of `a` and returning a list of `a`. But when using `tupelTurn` and `dateTurn` you change the type of values inside the list. Therefore Haskell cannot agree with this.

Comment: Depending on what you want, it may be better to create a data type instantiating the `Ord` class or create comparing functions (mimicking `>` and `<=`) for your type.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code. Let me list a few.

First, mind that this is a recursive definition!

```
where x = dateTurn (tupleTurn x)
```

as soon as you will evaluate `x` your code will hang in this equation, or if you are lucky, GHC will detect the loop and will stop your program with a `<<loop>>` exception.

You probably want something like

```
where x2 = dateTurn (tupleTurn x)
```

Then

```
xs = dateTurn (tupleTurn xs)
```

does not work for the same reason. Further, `xs` is a list and `tupleTurn` expects a single element, leading to a type error.

Moreover, you are trying to swap lists inside `quickSortDate`. However, by doing this you are not realizing that they will be swapped at each `quickSortDate` recursive call. This looks terribly wrong.

Another error: defined types must start with a capital letter e.g. `type Name = ...`.

There are probably other errors I can not spot right now.

My suggestion: write a *standard* quicksort. Then define your own `<=` operator, e.g.

```
lessThanOrEqual :: Person -> Person -> Bool
lessThanOrEqual (name1,(d1,m1,y1)) (name2,(d2,m2,y2)) = ...
```

then change the `x <= y` comparison in `quickSortDate` to `lessThanOrEqual x y`.